# Cannot install ros-humble-turtlebot3-gazebo package

Tags: ubuntu, packages

I follow this one https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html but the gazebo package does not seem to exist for ROS2 humble on 22.04

```
pi@pi-ros-2:~$ sudo apt install ros-humble-turtlebot3-gazebo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-turtlebot3-gazebo
pi@pi-ros-2:~$ sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-gazebo-ros-pkgs

pi@pi-ros-2:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here

```
https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-nav2-tutorial/
```

voilà

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-turtlebot3*
```

Comment: This answer does not meet our requirements for a good answer. Please include the solution here in case the linked website goes offline in three future.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem, after a long time trying, I think that it may have a relationship with your CPU. If you use an ARM CPU,  there is no package named as ros-humble-turtlebot3-gazebo, if you use an AMD CPU, you can get the package ros-humble-turtlebot3-gazebo easily. Maybe developers have not supply this package for system with ARM CPU